# Nivo Slider div positions outside main container div only on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a slider here

http://www.inspirativearts.co.uk/

On all browsers it works as designed, however on Firefox it is outside the main container.

Any ideas on the CSS issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have elements with float:left; They must have overflow:hidden; around them or something like that.

Add `<div class="clear"></div>` after .fullmenu

```
.clear {
    clear:both; 
    width:100%;
    line-height:0; 
    font-size:0;
}
```

or use this html `<div class="fullmenu clearfix"></div>`

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: '\0020';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0; 
}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix {zoom: 1;}
```

Comment: Thank you, however a simple fix was adding clear:both to .maincontainer - that seemed to fix it in the end.